# radio button code ok in firefox but don't work in other browsers

Tags: php, css, forms, radio-button

The given code works in firefox, but not in any other browser.

Am i going about it wrong by using radio button

I just want 3 buttons but styled as i have already, when the user clicks an option its highlighted

Here is my Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title></title>
</head>
<style>
.radio > input[type=radio]{
  display:none;
  visibility:hidden;
}
input[type=radio] + label{
  cursor:pointer;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label{
  background-color:green;
}

.but1{
    background-color:#009;
    color:#FFF;
    border:none;
    border-radius:15px;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-radius:15px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:8px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form action="Untitled2.php" method="post">
<label class="radio" for="fb1">
    <input id="fb1" type="radio" name="time" value="all day" checked />
    <label class="but1">Available<br>All day</label>
  </label>

  <label class="radio" for="fb2">
    <input id="fb2" type="radio" name="time" value="between 8-12"/>
    <label class="but1">Between<br>8am - 12am</label>
  </label>

  <label class="radio" for="fb3">
     <input id="fb3" type="radio" name="time" value="between 12-4" />
    <label class="but1">Between<br>12pm - 4pm</label>
  </label>

<input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VE9Tf/

Comment: browser dosen't support this way , Please use jQuery

Comment: ok try this link goo.gl/v810ki in all browsers, same code

Comment: Not too keyed up on jquery, any example would be appreciated

Comment: Its not working on my chrome http://www.sos-tyres.co.uk/Untitled2.php

Comment: doesnt work in chrome or explorer, strange that it only works in firefox

Comment: just checked ipad, works in safari too. is there a work around?

Comment: please check http://jsfiddle.net/VE9Tf/1/  , Worked by jQuery

Comment: ok going to try your code now, 2 secs

Comment: ok iv put your code as u have put it goto goo.gl/v810ki to see. doesnt work in all browsers also i want to remove radio buttons

Answer (score 2):

Your outer `label` is redundant, you can instead do it this way:

```
<input id="fb1" type="radio" name="time" value="all day" checked />
<label class="but1" for="fb1">Available<br>All day</label>

<input id="fb2" type="radio" name="time" value="between 8-12"/>
<label class="but1" for="fb2">Between<br>8am - 12am</label>

<input id="fb3" type="radio" name="time" value="between 12-4" />
<label class="but1" for="fb3">Between<br>12pm - 4pm</label>
```

Also the css for hiding your radio button was wrong, should be just:

```
input[type=radio]{
  display:none;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gz2G/)**

Answer (score 0):

Updated , Please check the url

Used jQuery as you mentioned  http://jsfiddle.net/VE9Tf/4/

```
<label class="radio" for="fb1">
    <input id="fb1" type="radio" name="time" value="all day" checked />
    <span class="but1 active">Available<br>All day</span>
  </label>

  <label class="radio" for="fb2">
    <input id="fb2"  type="radio" name="time" value="between 8-12"/>
    <span class="but1">Between<br>8am - 12am</span>
  </label>

  <label class="radio" for="fb3">
    <input id="fb3" type="radio" name="time" value="between 12-4" />
    <span class="but1">Between<br>12pm - 4pm</span>
  </label>
```

Comment: @ShibinRagh Umm your code wasn't working probably because the checkboxes were not getting checked, I edited your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VE9Tf/3/)

Comment: Updated , Please check the Answer again

Comment: ok its working in firefox and chrome and safari, but not in explorer. why is explorer such a pain in the ass, people should boycot using it

Comment: goo.gl/v810ki ..... is the link to try it... sorry it is working in explorer but i want to hide the radio buttons

Comment: Please my run on your local server , i think jsfiddle dosent work well on IE

Comment: @ShibinRagh iv tried your code, it works ok until i try and set the radio button to display none. then it stops working

Comment: Any one know of any other soloution? maybe without using radio buttons?

Comment: Still u have a problem in ie ?

Comment: yhh still got the problem in ie. basically all i want is 3 buttons, when active to change color, then parse the value of that button using php.

Comment: as you can see the code i have originally works in firefox and safari but no other browsers. they dont change color. [link](http://goo.gl/v810ki)